# Remove style tags from head

Tags: filters, wp-head

is there a filter for **removing style-tags** from the `<head></head>` area in wordpress?

I want remove this style for instance:

```
<head>
     <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chilanka&display=swap');
    </style>
</head>
```

I already achieved to remove link-tags by using this wordpress filter and some regex:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'removeGoogleLinks');
```

I guess i havbe to use **wp_head** somehow but I'm not sure how to use this as filter?

```
add_filter( 'wp_head',  $removeGoogleFontStyle); 

public function removeGoogleFontStyle($content){
   //Filter googleapi styles with regex but
   //how to use this funtion/filter?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My **solution** removes now all `<link></link>` tags and `<style>@import url()</style>` googleapi entries in the given HTML:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'SPDSGVOPublic::removeGoogleFonts' );


     /**
     * Remove all occurrences of google fonts
     */
    public static function removeGoogleFonts()
    {
        ob_start();
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        $patternImportUrl = '/(@import[\s]url\((?:"|\')((?:https?:)?\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com\/css(?:(?!\1).)+)(?:"|\')\)\;)/';
        $patternLinkTag = '/<link(?:\s+(?:(?!href\s*=\s*)[^>])+)?(?:\s+href\s*=\s*([\'"])((?:https?:)?\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com\/css(?:(?!\1).)+)\1)(?:\s+[^>]*)?>/';

        preg_match_all($patternImportUrl, $content, $matchesImportUrl);
        preg_match_all($patternLinkTag, $content, $matchesLinkTag);

        $matches = array_merge($matchesImportUrl,$matchesLinkTag);

        foreach( $matches as $match ) {
            $content = str_replace( $match, '', $content );
        }

        echo $content;
    }
```